# TextInputLayout Hint gravity bottom

Tags: android, material-design

The Hint is always vertically centred and I want it to be aligned to the bottom of the view close to the border with a bit padding. I managed to do it for the text of the `TextInputEditText` but I cannot do it for the hint.

Here's how it looks

[image: I want the hint to be with the padding of the EditText text pisition]

And here is my layout XML:

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/first_name_layout"
            style="@style/My.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/first_name"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/first_name_edit_text"
                style="@style/TextInputEditTextForm"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

And my `styles.xml`

```
<style name="My.TextInputLayout.FilledBox" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/MyThemeOverlayFilledPadding</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">bottom</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/gray</item>
    <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/grey_little</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeWidth">0.5dp</item>
    <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/FormInputLabel</item>
    <item name="hintTextColor">@color/gray</item>
</style>

<style name="MyThemeOverlayFilledPadding">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/gray_light</item>
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/MyTextInputEditText_filledBox_padding</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTextInputEditText_filledBox_padding" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.FilledBox">
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>
</style>

<style name="TextInputEditTextForm" >
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">bottom</item>
    <item name="android:lines">1</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/gray_x_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_xx_small</item>
</style>

<style name="MyThemeOverlayFilledPaddingHint">
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">bottom</item>
</style>

<style name="FormInputLabel" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_xxxx_small</item>
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/MyThemeOverlayFilledPaddingHint</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">bottom</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The hint is drawn by helper class CollapsingTextHelper which is available in private-package scope.
You can access the field via reflection but accessing private field is only available on pre Orea devices

Comment: I need to target also newer versions

Comment: Even with reflection and 'setExpandedTextGravity' it wasn't working on older and newer versions of the OS